# Having troubles integrating Twitter, Facebook , Google SignIn with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, twitter-oauth, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

**Having troubles integrating Twitter, Facebook , Google SignIn with Firebase**

I tried integrating Google , Twitter and Facebook into my android app . but i was not able to do it . i did it using email and password but cant' do it using these three. Can some one guide me or five me the source code for it . 
I found ad demo code on twitter but its not working also it includes some irrelevant stuff so its hard to understand. 
Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

> This is done by integrating your application with the respective **SDK** for these featues to work.
>   Search google for android integration and there will be a standard procedure given on the website.

Comment: yes the procedure is given but its not as good to integrate it as i mentioned above

Comment: That method is pretty easy, I have integrated SDKs for the above following that method only. I am not following which method you are proposing, please elaborate.